# how to send ajax data before page is close?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I want to send a value to the database when the user closes the page such as online and offline , I hope to find the solution I have tried for more than 7 hours
But does not work

```
<script tysssspe="text/javascript">
//ST
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  var user_st = "0";
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",url:"inc/offline.php",
    data:"user_st="+user_st
  });
}
//SD
</script>
```

To offline.php

```
<?php
tab
include "connect.php";
$UID = $_COOKIE["ID"];
$online_status = $_POST['user_st'];
$setStatus = $conn->prepare("UPDATE accounts SET online = :online_status WHERE id = :UID");
$setStatus->bindParam(':online_status',$online_status,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$setStatus->bindParam(':UID',$UID,PDO::PARAM_INT);
$setStatus->execute();
?>
```

Comment: what do you get when you print_r($_POST['user_st']); and print_r($_COOKIE["ID"]);

Comment: try to if (!$setStatus->execute()) {
    print_r($setStatus->errorInfo());
}

Comment: `print_r($_POST['user_st']); and print_r($_COOKIE["ID"]);`

AND 

`if(!$setStatus->execute()){
    print_r($setStatus->errorInfo());
}`
Nothing happens ?

Comment: in `inc/offline.php`

Comment: What response are you getting from the call? put in a success and error callback and log the results.
`$.ajax({
    type:"POST",url:"inc/offline.php",
    data:"user_st="+user_st,
    success:function(data){ console.log(data);}
  });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onbeforeunload will work in some browser (Chrome), but not in others. (Safari , FF and IE).

There was a workaround is to make the ajax synchronous,

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(){
  var user_st = "0";
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",url:"inc/offline.php",
    data:"user_st="+user_st,
    async: false
  });
}
```

but Synchronous Ajax is deprecated. You can try if you can accept deprecated methods.

If you doesn't require the online/offline to be 100% real time, one solution could be instead of reporting offline, let the user to report online (every 30 seconds, if server doesn't receive online update for more than 30 seconds, it treats this user as offline.) Potential disadvantage is that more db calls. (Do you need it to be persisted to database? Can it be in memcache? )

Comment: Thank you. It has worked and you can write an example of how verification works every 30 seconds ?

Comment: The project I did is actually using websocket and redis. There is a TTL defined in the redis cache, so that if it's not update in 30 seconds, it will be evicted. Your application code only need handle the update cache.

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax call, try using an absolute URL instead of a relative one. Ex: `/inc/offline.php`

Comment: Nothing happens ?

Comment: and this not working too `<script type="text/javascript">
//ST
window.onbeforeunload = function set_offline(){
  var user_st = "0";
  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",url:"127.0.0.1/inc/offline.php",
    data:"user_st="+user_st
  });
  return set_offline();
}
//SD
</script>`